# Can someone recommend me a good image upload script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-upload

I'm looking for one of those fancy upload scripts you see on some sites that upload the file the moment you select it on your hard disk, and optionally allows you to crop to a portion of the original image.

We use PHP and Prototype (so preferable no jQuery plugins... even though we should probably switch).

We currently have a server side script takes it's input from  fields, but it's very unstable and only supports JPEG and PNG, and *some* GIF files, so we've been looking for a replacement for a while now, but I'm having a hard time finding anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options you can investigate here. Look for the word "asynchronous":

http://www.ajaxrain.com/tag?tag=upload

This one may meet your needs: http://thecodecentral.com/2007/09/04/asynchronous-file-upload-yuis-approach
Another option: http://tomas.epineer.se/archives/3

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like valums' uploader, which is based on actual AJAX calls in browsers that support that kind of thing, and falls back nicely to the old-skool multi-part mime post where not supported (IE).

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/